# ASP.NET C# zipping files on server very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I need to get like 100 files form a database, zip them and download them. It goes too slow. What is wrong?

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdReport2.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkEmp1");
                if (ChkBoxRows.Checked == true)
                {
                    MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand();
                    try
                    {
                        string chave = row.Cells[2].Text;

                        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        sqlCommand.Connection = cnn;
                        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT xml FROM cte WHERE chCTe = '" + chave + "'";
                        dynamic k = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        if (k.Read() == true)
                        {
                            string xml = k["xml"];
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(zippath + "\\" + chave + "-procCTe.xml", xml);
                            oneIsDone = true;

                        }
                        k.Close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { string a = ex.Message; }

                    sqlCommand.Dispose();
                    sqlCommand = null;
                }
            }

            if (oneIsDone)
            {
                try
                {
                    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zippath, System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + t + "nfe.zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + lblClient.Text + " " + cbTipo.SelectedItem.Text + txtfrom.Text.Replace("//", "-") + "|" + txtTo.Text.Replace("//", "-") + ".zip");
                    Response.TransmitFile(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + t + "nfe.zip");
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/zip";
                    Response.Flush();
                }
                catch { }
                Response.End();

            }
        }
```

Comment: how long is too slow for you? how big are the files?

Comment: minutes. Like one minute for 10 files. Could be the database. I'm testing